# Selectively suppress output in sweave/knitr document

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I am calling a function from a library in a code block in my Sweave document. The function prints a lot of progress messages. I want to suppress/hide the printed messages from the function. In the mean time I want to also display the output from the code block itself. I tried using `warning=FALSE`, `message=FALSE`. But it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be really appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: What kind of function is it? How does it print progress messages?

Comment: if the function is printing using `print()` or `cat()`, you're probably stuck.  Reproducible example please?

Comment: you could try wrapping the function call in `capture.output` or `sink()`, perhaps

Comment: I had the same problem with `readLines()` but fortunately this function has an option to set `warn=F`. Check if your function has this option. It would be better if you could show some of your reproducible example.